# how to understand the mechanism of backslash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm learning bash. when I tried to enter

```
echo {a,b,c} ,{\ 1," 2",' 3'}
```

It returns

```
a b c , 1 , 2 , 3
```

While I tried to enter

```
echo {a,b,c}\ ,{\ 1," 2",' 3'}
```

It returns

```
a , 1 a , 2 a , 3 b , 1 b , 2 b , 3 c , 1 c , 2 c , 3
```

I've noticed the only difference is the second command contains `\`. Can someone explain the mechanism of `\` or how two commands work differently? Thanks!

Comment: it "escapes" the space char following it. This keeping the whole cmd-line as one string to be evaluated by the shell. Try `echo {a,b,c},{\ 1," 2",' 3'}` and `echo {a,b,c}{\ 1," 2",' 3'}` VS `echo {a,b,c} {\ 1," 2",' 3'}`  . Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space acts as an IFS (Internal Field Seperator). The first example

```
echo {a,b,c} ,{\ 1," 2",' 3'}
```

There are two distinct groups `{a,b,c}` and `,{\ 1," 2",' 3'}`. That first one is printed out, then the second one is expanded and printed (comma and then each item in the sequence).

In your second example, the backslash escapes the IFS which tells your shell that it's a literal space character. So

```
echo {a,b,c}\ ,{\ 1," 2",' 3'}
```

expands out each item from the first combining with 1 space and 1 comma and then each item from the second sequence producing:

```
 a , 1 a , 2 a , 3 b , 1 b , 2 b , 3 c , 1 c , 2 c , 3
```

`a , 1` and `a , 2` and `a , 3` and `b , 1` and so on as each combination (which are then separated by a space, again because it is IFS by default).